# Setting aws s3 storage class from media convert Job/service?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-media-convert

I'm using aws s3 and media convert services.

I setup s3 bucket with storage class as **Intelligent tiering**.

When I upload file from API to S3 bucket, all files are storing in **Intelligent tiering**, but media convert jobs output files are storing as **Standard**.

Is there any way to pass/set storage class from media convert job?

Answer (score 2):

AWS Elemental MediaConvert output to S3 will always be created with the **S3 Standard** storage class - there is no method to modify storage class at the time of object creation (regardless of whether you use the AWS console or the AWS CLI for job creation).

The simplest workaround would be to assign lifecycle rules to the S3 bucket to transition objects to the **Intelligent-Tiering** storage class.

Documentation for S3 object lifecycle management can be found here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/object-lifecycle-mgmt.html

Comment: Hi there, welcome to SO! This is a good answer - it could be even better if it linked to relevant documentation on 1. why or 2. how to do what it suggests :)